# Postgres not using index for range query in partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, indexing, partitioning, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-performance

I found that Postgres is not using an index for a range query on a partitioned table.

The parent table and its partitions have their date column indexed using btree.

A query like this:

```
select * from parent_table where date >= '2015-07-01';
```

does not use indexes.

`EXPLAIN` result:

```
Append  (cost=0.00..106557.52 rows=3263963 width=128)
->  Seq Scan on parent_table  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=640)
    Filter: (date >= '2015-07-01'::date)
->  Seq Scan on z_partition_2015_07  (cost=0.00..106546.02 rows=3263922 width=128)
    Filter: (date >= '2015-07-01'::date)
->  Seq Scan on z_partition_2015_08  (cost=0.00..11.50 rows=40 width=640)
    Filter: (date >= '2015-07-01'::date)
```

But a query like this:

```
select * from parent_table where date = '2015-07-01'
```

uses an index.

`EXPLAIN` result:

```
    Append  (cost=0.00..30400.95 rows=107602 width=128)
->  Seq Scan on parent_table  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=640)
    Filter: (date = '2015-07-01'::date)
->  Index Scan using z_partition_2015_07_date on z_partition_2015_07  (cost=0.43..30400.95 rows=107601 width=128)
    Index Cond: (date = '2015-07-01'::date)
```

When I run the query on a different normal table with `date` indexed, both queries use the index.

Anything particular that we should do on partitioned table index?

Comment: try use date between condition

Comment: Show the explain analyze plans for both of them.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing about size of your data and its structure. First of all try `VACUUM ANALYZE parent_table` to collect statistics on your partitioned table. If it didn't help try in psql `SET enable_seqscan = off` and repeat your query. Planner should use index scan so you could compare costs of seqscan and indexscan. Most likely seqscan is simply cheaper for this type of query. Indexscan is not very good at fetching large amounts of data.

Comment: @AdamSilenko Still the same with between

Comment: @Musin  Yes, the partition contains about 3 million rows, and the query will pull about 10% of it.

Comment: probably answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007523/how-can-i-use-an-index-on-a-partitioned-table-in-postgresql-8-3-7) will be helpful (looks similar to your problem)

Comment: Run `SET enable_seqscan = off` and then `explain select * from parent_table where date >= '2015-07-01'`. Does it cost more than seqscan?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are aware that "partitions" are **separate tables** in Postgres. Indexes are typically ***not*** used when retrieving large parts of a table (more than ~ 5 %, it depends on many details), because it's typically faster to just scan the table sequentially in such cases.

What's more, it seems like you select *all* rows from the involved partitions in your first query. No use for indexes ...

Generally, an equality predicate with `=` is more **selective** than a predicate with `>=`.Think about it:

Your first query with `date >= '2015-07-01'` retrieves **all rows** from the partition (guessing, I would need to see the exact definition). Using the index would just add overhead cost. But your second query with `date = '2015-07-01'` only fetches a **small percentage**. Postgres expects an index scan to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

maybe that's just faster that way? run your query, then do this:

```
SET enable_seqscan=false
```

And run it again.